# Restrict First Number in Numerical String to 2 to 9

Tags: jquery

I have implemented this jquery code in my site's sandbox and it functions ***almost*** perfectly on an input box in a form. It formats the phone number as it is typed. The issue is the string is restricted to 14 characters, and if a visitor enters a 0 or 1 as the first character the phone number is sent via email and is invalid. How can I restrict a user from entering a 0 or a 1 as the first character?

All my business will be local so there is no need for international telephone formatting. Only North American formatting is required. Before I go live with this I would appreciate any input that will help solve my issue.

Thank you,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  /***phone number format***/
  $(".phone-format").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = $(this).val();
    if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf("(") <= -1) {
      $(this).val("(" + curval + ")" + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 4 && curval.indexOf("(") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + ")-");
    } else if (curchr == 5 && curval.indexOf(")") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 9) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
      $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your Phone (Numbers Only)" class="phone-format" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another posible jquery idea you could extend to handle input control based on `.on` events like `keydown` and `input` to restrict inputting.

See comments in js script below to understand the input event restriction handling...

```js
// jquery on ready
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // phone input constant
  const $phone = $('[name="phone"');

  // phone input keydown events (using .on method)
  $phone.on('keydown', function(e) {

    // current event function phone input value var
    let val = $(this).val();

    // keydown cursor position
    let cursorPos = e.target.selectionStart;

    // if cursor position is 0
    if (cursorPos === 0) {

      // if first phone input keydown event is 1 or 0 then
      if (e.key === '1' || e.key === '0') {

        // prevent keydown event
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

      }

    }

  // phone input changed event (copy and paste value restriction)
  }).on('input', function(e) {

    // current event function phone input value var
    let val = $(this).val();

    // if copy and pasted phone value begins with 0 or 1
    if (val.startsWith("0") || val.startsWith("1")) {

      // empty phone input value
      $phone.val('');

      // alert or error 
      alert('You cant paste a phone number beginning with 0 or 1');

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="1234567890" required>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very nice. Invalid paste protection is a nice touch. I had that issue addressed in the POST call, but your method is much cleaner.

Comment: @Stephen no worries. Did you end up using this solution? Can you mark question as solved to close this question if it worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving the value, use a regular expression to remove the leading number of it's 0 or 1:

```
$(this).val().replace(/^[01]/, '');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  /***phone number format***/
  $(".phone-format").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = $(this).val().replace(/^[01]/, '');
    if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf("(") <= -1) {
      $(this).val("(" + curval + ")" + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 4 && curval.indexOf("(") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + ")-");
    } else if (curchr == 5 && curval.indexOf(")") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 9) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
      $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your Phone (Numbers Only)" class="phone-format" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer still permits a malformed phone number if the user enters a 1 followed by a 0, or vice versa.

I added this line to the code and it works now:

```
if (curchr == 1 && curval == 1 || curchr == 1 && curval == 0) {
  $(this).val("");
} else
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  /***phone number format***/
  $(".phone-format").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = $(this).val().replace(/^[01]/, '');
    if (curchr == 1 && curval == 1 || curchr == 1 && curval == 0) {
      $(this).val("");
    } else if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf("(") <= -1) {
      $(this).val("(" + curval + ")" + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 4 && curval.indexOf("(") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + ")-");
    } else if (curchr == 5 && curval.indexOf(")") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 9) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
      $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your Phone (Numbers Only)" class="phone-format" required>
</div>
```